# Can't get my tables to alternate colors for rows on live version of my site

Tags: html, css, html-table

For some reason this works on my testing site, but not the live version.  I've re-uploaded all my files, but nothing changed.   help is appreciated.  I have the css set to color all the even rows of my tables.  I don't know what more details to write, but it wants me to write more details.   So here are more details.. :/

```
<html data-ember-extension="1" class="gr__irodemine_com">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.8">
    <title>Divinity Original Sin 2 Crafting</title>

    <style>
.outputtable{
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 800px;
}


select {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    padding: 2px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    padding: 2px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
table {
          -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
        </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div align="center"><img align="center" src="images/divinity-original-sin-2-logo.png" /></div>
    <div id="tabs17" class="">
        <div class="ui red three item inverted menu">
            <a class="active item" title="Divinity Original Sin 2 Home" class="current">Divinity Original Sin 2</a>
            <a class="item" href="divinity2.php" title="Crafting" class="current">Crafting</a>
            <a class="item" href="skills.php" title="Skills">Skills</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <form id="form1" action="divinity2.php">
        <table frame="border" cellpadding="5" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Select a Category</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="selection" id="selection">
                        <option value = "0" SELECTED>ALL</option>
                        <option value = "1" >Weapons</option>
                        <option value = "2" >Potions</option>
                        <option value = "3" >Grenades</option>
                        <option value = "4" >Arrows & Arrow Heads</option>
                        <option value = "5" >Armor & Upgrades</option>
                        <option value = "6" >Food & Drink</option>
                        <option value = "7" >Misc</option>
                        <option value = "8" >Runes & components</option>
                        <option value = "9" >Scrolls & Books</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Search Text</td>
                <td><input type='text' id='searchMe' onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" onfocus="javascript:uncheckExact(this);" name='searchMe'value ="feather"></input><input type="checkbox"  id="exactsearch" name="exactsearch" />exact search</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><button type="submit">Search</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div class="ui container">
    <table align='center' frame='border' class='divinitytable'><th>ITEM(S) CREATED</th><th>COMPONENTS</th><th>DESCRIPTION</th><tr><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Teleportation Scroll&exactsearch=on' >Teleportation Scroll</a></p></td><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Sheet of Paper&exactsearch=on' >Sheet of Paper</a></p><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Air Essence&exactsearch=on' >Air Essence</a></p><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Feather&exactsearch=on' >Feather</a></p></td><td>Teleportation description not yet entered.</td></tr><tr><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Teleportation Scroll&exactsearch=on' >Teleportation Scroll</a></p></td><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Sheet of Paper&exactsearch=on' >Sheet of Paper</a></p><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=| High Quality Air Essence |&exactsearch=on' >| High Quality Air Essence |</a></p><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Feather&exactsearch=on' >Feather</a></p></td><td>Teleportation description not yet entered.</td></tr><tr><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Teleportation Scroll&exactsearch=on' >Teleportation Scroll</a></p></td><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Sheet of Paper&exactsearch=on' >Sheet of Paper</a></p><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=| Alien Air Essence |&exactsearch=on' >| Alien Air Essence |</a></p><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Feather&exactsearch=on' >Feather</a></p></td><td>Teleportation description not yet entered.</td></tr><tr><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Tornado Scroll&exactsearch=on' >Tornado Scroll</a></p></td><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Sheet of Paper&exactsearch=on' >Sheet of Paper</a></p><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=| Alien Air Essence |&exactsearch=on' >| Alien Air Essence |</a></p><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Fancy Feather&exactsearch=on' >Fancy Feather</a></p></td><td>Tornado description not yet entered.</td></tr><tr><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Feather&exactsearch=on' >Feather</a></p></td><td><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=Pillow&exactsearch=on' >Pillow</a></p><p><a href='divinity2.php?selection=ALL&searchMe=CuttingTool&exactsearch=on' >CuttingTool</a></p></td><td>description not yet entered.</td></tr></table> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function uncheckExact(obj)
        {
            document.getElementById("exactsearch").checked = false;
        }
</script>
</body>
```

And then the CSS is as follows

```
//*- Menu Tabs 17--------------------------- */
    #tabs17 {
      font: bold 11px/1.5em Verdana;
      width:100%;
      background:change-background;
      line-height:normal;

      }
    #tabs17 ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 10px 0 50px;
    list-style:none;
      }
    #tabs17 li {
      display:inline;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      }
    #tabs17 a {
      float:left;
      background:url("images/tableft17.gif") no-repeat left top;
      margin:0;
      padding:0 0 0 4px;
      text-decoration:none;
      }
    #tabs17 a span {
      float:left;
      display:block;
      background:url("images/tabright17.gif") no-repeat right top;
      padding:5px 15px 4px 6px;
      color:#FFF;
      }
    /* Commented Backslash Hack hides rule from IE5-Mac*
    #tabs17 a span {float:none;}
    /* End IE5-Mac hack 
    #tabs17 a:hover span {
      color:#FFF;
      }
    #tabs17 a:hover {
      background-position:0% -42px;
      }
    #tabs17 a:hover span {
      background-position:100% -42px;
      }
*/
    .divinitytable {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-spacing: 2px 5px;
    }
    .divinitytable tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
```

Comment: you have an error syntax when including CSS, check your code

Comment: the error is before the include of CDN

Comment: You have added your style.css the wrong way.